# UpdatePannel trigger itemcommand if repeater in repeater asp.net

Tags: asp.net

[image]

How can I trigger ItemCommand event of repeater in repeater. The example is in picture. Please help.....

Comment: please click the image to get more infomation about example

Comment: Why not post the code as text so people can reproduce your situation easily?

Comment: Niki Mihaylov - this is the first time I post my question to stackoverflow, I tried but it alert some error, so I post via image. if you know the answer, please help.... tks

Comment: From the docs: 

This event is raised when a button in the Repeater control is clicked.

This event causes a round-trip from the client to occur.

Comment: more help....please